# Download multiple csv files from a web directory using Python and store them in disk, using as filename the anchor text

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

From this URL:
http://vs-web-fs-1.oecd.org/piaac/puf-data/CSV

I want to download all the files and save them with the text of the anchor tag. I guess my main struggle is to retrieve the text of the anchor tag right now:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib.request

url_base = "http://vs-web-fs-1.oecd.org"
url_dir = "http://vs-web-fs-1.oecd.org/piaac/puf-data/CSV"

r  = requests.get(url_dir)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,features="html5lib")

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if link.get('href').endswith(".csv"):
        print(link.find("a"))
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url_base+link.get('href'), "test.csv")
```

Line `print(link.find("a"))` returns `None`. How can I retrieve the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the text accessing the *content*, like this:

```
link.contents[0]
```

or

```
link.string
```